# Why doesnt decrypting work in my RSA in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, rsa

So i'm programming RSA in python with gui in qt designer and can't find out what is wrong with my decrypting function.
I start with spliting the message into blocks. Block size is based on log2(n). After that i take one block, turn every character into it's ASCII value and then it's binary value. If the character's binary value is less than eleven i add zeros to the left after that i turn the block in binary into it's decimal form. Now i encrypt every block using cipher = message^e mod n and print encrypted blocks.
For decrypting i take each block from encrypted message and use message = cipher^d mod n, then get block's binary value and check if there is enough characters for deviding by eleven and add zeros to the beggining if not. Now i split the block into parts every 11 characters and take each part to get it's decimal value and from that I turn it into ASCII character.

The problem beggins when decrypting one part of the message using *message = cipher^d mod n* because it return different value then it was before encrypting

```
import binascii
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtGui, uic
import random
import sympy
import math

qtCreatorFile = "RSAGUI.ui"

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)


class MyApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def keys_gen(self):
        p = random.randint(1, 100)#10 ** 18, 10 ** 19 - 1
        while not sympy.isprime(p):
            p = random.randint(1, 100)#10 ** 18, 10 ** 19 - 1
        q = random.randint(1, 100)#10 ** 18, 10 ** 19 - 1
        while not sympy.isprime(q) and q != p:
            q = random.randint(1, 100)#10 ** 18, 10 ** 19 - 1
        n = p * q
        euler = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
        e = random.randint(2, euler)
        while math.gcd(e, euler) != 1:
            e = random.randint(2, euler)
        d = sympy.mod_inverse(e, euler)
        self.lineEditNPublic.setText(str(n))
        self.lineEditE.setText(str(e))
        self.lineEditNPrivate.setText(str(n))
        self.lineEditD.setText(str(d))

    def text_to_num(self, text):
        num = ""
        for char in text:
            char_bin = bin(ord(char))[2:]
            num += char_bin.rjust(11, '0')
        num = int(num, 2)
        return num

    def num_to_text(self, num):
        num_bin = bin(num)[2:]
        if len(num_bin) % 11 != 0:
            zeros = 11 - (len(num_bin) % 11)
            num_bin = num_bin.rjust(len(num_bin) + zeros, '0')
        num_bin_parts = [num_bin[i:i + 11] for i in range(0, len(num_bin), 11)]
        text = ""
        for part in num_bin_parts:
            part_decimal = int(part, 2)
            text += chr(part_decimal)
        return text

    def encrypt(self):
        text = self.plainTextEditDDecrypted.toPlainText()
        n = int(self.lineEditNPublic.text())
        e = int(self.lineEditE.text())
        text_encrypted = ""
        block_size = math.floor(math.log2(n))
        block_size_counter = 0
        block = ""
        for ch in text:
            block_size_counter += 1
            block += ch
            if (block_size_counter % block_size) == 0 or block_size_counter == len(text):
                block = self.text_to_num(block)
                block = pow(block, e, n)
                text_encrypted += str(block) + ","
                block = ""
        if text_encrypted[-1] == ",":
            text_encrypted = text_encrypted[:-1]
        self.plainTextEditDEncrypted.setPlainText(str(text_encrypted))

    def decrypt(self):
        numbers = str(self.plainTextEditEEncrypted.toPlainText())
        n = int(self.lineEditNPrivate.text())
        d = int(self.lineEditD.text())
        text = ""
        number_list = [int(num) for num in numbers.split(",")]
        for number in number_list:
            number = pow(number, d, n)
            text += self.num_to_text(number)
        self.plainTextEditEDecrypted.setPlainText(text)

    def delete_encrypt(self):
        self.plainTextEditDDecrypted.setPlainText("")
        self.plainTextEditDEncrypted.setPlainText("")

    def delete_decrypt(self):
        self.plainTextEditEEncrypted.setPlainText("")
        self.plainTextEditEDecrypted.setPlainText("")

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButtonEncrypt.clicked.connect(self.encrypt)
        self.pushButtonDelete1.clicked.connect(self.delete_encrypt)
        self.pushButtonDecrypt.clicked.connect(self.decrypt)
        self.pushButtonDelete2.clicked.connect(self.delete_decrypt)
        self.pushButtonKeyGenerate.clicked.connect(self.keys_gen)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried using lower values for keys in case there was problem with the math.pow funciton

Answer (score 0):

The code calculates the block size in bits, but the code then uses that blocksize on characters. It's not clear why each character is 11 bits in size, it makes more sense for them to be e.g. 7 or 8 bits in size. However, if characters are 11 bits in size then you need to have a block size that is log_2(n) / 11 instead of log_2(n) / 11 (also known as log_256 by the way).